# How do I exit the loop when I use .equalsIgnoreCase

Tags: java, do-while, control-flow

I designed a program which asks the user to enter anything.

The program should terminate once the user has typed in the word 'STOP'. However I am a bit confused with the .equalsIgnoreCase method.

This is the code which works properly:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        name = scan.next();
        System.out.println(name);

        //Keep looping until the name does not equal stop, once it equals stop
        //then stop the program 
    } while(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"));
    System.out.println("Program Terminated!");
    scan.close();
}
 }
```

but during my initial attempt, I tried the following code in the while(),

```
while(name.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"));
```

I did not use the `!`, because the logic I had in my head was that the string name will be simply compared to 'STOP' e.g. Terminate the program when the String name = STOP however upon running that code I found that the program terminates after only 1 loop, so no matter what the user typed in the program terminated after looping once, but then when I set the logic to keep looping while name does not equal STOP. The program started working properly, why is that the case? Why does it not work with the initial try?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try entering `stop` when you ran the first version of your code? What was the result?

Comment: do you know what `while` means? (you are probably mistaking it with `until`, which does not exist in java)

Comment: Statement for checking a particular condition, e.g. Keep looping while a file has a next line

Comment: `do` this code `while` my `name` is *not* `"STOP"`. The *not* is the `!` If you take out the `!`, then read what you get.

Comment: Yeah I think thats where my confusion is

Comment: but then why does it terminate without the ! upon entering any word after the first loop?

Comment: `do while` loops will execute the loop once, then look at the `while` condition. Where as a `while` loop considers it before executing

Comment: I tried your code and it worked properly

Answer (score 0):

Your loop keeps running while the statement is true.  In your case this means:

```
while(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"))
```

So, if your name equals "STOP", the statement returns true (loop keeps running), but since you negate the result of the statement it keeps running as long as your name does not equal "STOP".

Your first attempt would run as long the statement is true -> as long as the name equals "STOP".